# scrapy yield Request not working

Tags: scrapy

I wrote the following scrapy spider but it's not continuing the crawling process after the initial request, although I've `yield`ed more `scrapy.Request`s for scrapy to follow.

```
import regex as re
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

class myspider(Spider):
name = 'haha'

allowed_domains = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com/']
start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com/']
extractor = LinkExtractor(allow=allowed_domains)

def parse(self, response):
    # To extract all the links on this page
    links_in_page = self.extractor.extract_links(response)

    for link in links_in_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`allowed_domains` needs to be [a list of domains](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains), not a list of URLs.

So it should be:

```
allowed_domains = ['blog.scrapinghub.com']
```